# Getting Error on Sequelize with Postgres while trying to insert into table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am first time trying Sequelize and Postgres. I am trying to insert into table for very first time but am getting this error.

{
"name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
"parent": {
"length": 104,
"name": "error",
"severity": "ERROR",
"code": "42P01",
"position": "13",
"file": "parse_relation.c",
"line": "1449",
"routine": "parserOpenTable",
"sql": "INSERT INTO "users" ("user_id","user_name","user_email","user_password","user_image","total_orders") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "user_id","user_name","user_email","user_password","user_image","total_orders","created_at","last_logged_in";",
"parameters": [
"135c369f-23f6-4f20-8d25-e7cfad05187b",
"Anurag Parmar",
"anurag@gmail.com",
"$2b$05$l4TE19JJKbZsbswRjnPQ0.W9xnKAClaUTKrTbko8Bjs3EDyx00XWi",
"123456",
0
]
},
"original": {
"length": 104,
"name": "error",
"severity": "ERROR",
"code": "42P01",
"position": "13",
"file": "parse_relation.c",
"line": "1449",
"routine": "parserOpenTable",
"sql": "INSERT INTO "users" ("user_id","user_name","user_email","user_password","user_image","total_orders") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "user_id","user_name","user_email","user_password","user_image","total_orders","created_at","last_logged_in";",
"parameters": [
"135c369f-23f6-4f20-8d25-e7cfad05187b",
"Anurag Parmar",
"anurag@gmail.com",
"$2b$05$l4TE19JJKbZsbswRjnPQ0.W9xnKAClaUTKrTbko8Bjs3EDyx00XWi",
"123456",
0
]
},
"sql": "INSERT INTO "users" ("user_id","user_name","user_email","user_password","user_image","total_orders") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "user_id","user_name","user_email","user_password","user_image","total_orders","created_at","last_logged_in";",
"parameters": [
"135c369f-23f6-4f20-8d25-e7cfad05187b",
"Anurag Parmar",
"anurag@gmail.com",
"$2b$05$l4TE19JJKbZsbswRjnPQ0.W9xnKAClaUTKrTbko8Bjs3EDyx00XWi",
"123456",
0
]
}

Comment: Error code 42P01 translates to `undefined_table`. That means that your SQL statement uses a table name that does not exists in this database. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html